# Combining Textures with baking

Tags: texturing, texture-baking, baking

i am trying to combine tiled textures of edited peach castle from Mario 64.
H read i need to bake it, so i tried built in bake, but some parts become black.
I also tried principled bake addon, but it exports only 1 texture somewhy.
Am I making mistake somewhere ? or is there some another possible way ?
[here is download of my blend file](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1N4EFOJOLMtwcOl2-9n1PZih-ZSXy5vVI/view?usp=sharing).
here is how the texture tiles look like:[image]

[image: Principled baking]

[image: Built in baking in blender]

Answer (score 0):

hello is so easy just follow this steps:

1- add a mix node for your images you want to mix, and plug it to principled shader.

2- set the render sampling to 1 , and tile size to the size of your image.

3- set the bake option to diffuse, and uncheck direct and indirect, and choose a margin size (i recommend 1024px= 4px, 2048 px = 8 px, 4096px = 16px).

4- and then bake your image it should take a few seconds...also if your textures/materials are not in the same uv map it wont bake properly...
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]